# Simple solution to system of three equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I've been given the question;

> $$xy = \frac19$$
>   $$x(y+1) = \frac79$$
>   $$y(x+1) = \frac5{18}$$
>   What is the value of $(x+1)(y+1)$?

Of course, you could solve for $x$ and $y$, then substitute in the values. However, my teacher says there is a quick solution that only requires $2$ lines to solve.

How can I solve $(x+1)(y+1)$ without finding $x$ and $y$, given the values above?

Comment: Multiply 2 and 3 and you get $xy(x+1)(y+1)=35/(9\cdot 18$. Substitute xy form 1

Comment: You should change your title. This is not a linear system. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you multiply the second and third equation you will have $xy(y+1)(x+1)$ and you are given a value for $xy$. Simply divide by $xy$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the second by third then substitute the first.

Answer (score 1):

$$
(x+1)(y+1)=x(y+1)+y(x+1)-xy+1
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(x+1)=\frac5{18}\cdot\frac1y$$
$$(y+1)=\frac7{9}\cdot\frac1x$$
$$(x+1)(y+1)=\frac5{18}\cdot\frac1y\cdot\frac7{9}\cdot\frac1x=\frac{35}{162}\cdot9=\frac{35}{18}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$2xy+x+y=\frac{19}{18}$$

$$xy+x+y+1=(x+1)(y+1)=\frac{17}{18}+1=\frac{35}{18}$$

And this comes from combining the second and third equations, using the first equation to reduce the $2xy$ term to $xy$ and then adding one to both sides of the equality so that it matches what you are asked to find.

---

The other obvious solution:

since $xy=\frac{1}{9}$ you can do this

$$X(y+1)=\frac{7}{9}$$
$$xy+x=\frac{7}{9}$$
$$\frac{1}{9}+x=\frac{7}{9}$$

$$x=\frac{2}{3}$$

use this fact and find y:

$$\frac{2}{3}y=\frac{1}{9}$$

and then solving is trivial

Comment: Michaelwm asked how to find answer without finding $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @ mathematician171 - better?

Comment: The second solution is exactly what he asked for. It is solved in two lines.

Comment: @ Mathematician171 - Also, thanks for the heads up.  I went ahead and rearranged my answer so it matches his question.

Answer (score 0):

Without using any multiplications or divisions (except to bring the fractions to a common denominator):
$$(x+1)(y+1)=x(y+1)+y(x+1)-xy+1 =\frac{14+5-2+18}{18} = \frac{35}{18}.
$$